# Script not working after adding try and catch

Tags: sql-server, scripting, sqlcmd

I have a working script that I modified to work with `SQLCMD` since I need to invoke this script remotely.

Here is my script:

```
:ON ERROR EXIT
USE [master]
GO

BEGIN TRY

/****** Declare Database name ******/
DECLARE @server varchar(8000);
SET @server = N'script_test';

/****** Automatically set username since we have a convention for it ******/
DECLARE @user varchar(800);
SET @user = @server + '_sys';

/****** First kill all active connections to the db and then drop it if the db already exists ******/
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name= @server )
begin
DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), session_id) + ';'
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id  = db_id(@server)

EXECUTE(@kill);

EXECUTE('DROP DATABASE ' + @server)
end

/****** Create the database again ******/
DECLARE @Create_Template varchar(MAX) = 'CREATE DATABASE {SERVERNAME}
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY
( NAME = {SERVERNAME}, FILENAME = N''D:\MSSQL16.DATA\MSSQL\DATA\{SERVERNAME}.mdf'' , SIZE = 73728KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON
( NAME = {SERVERNAME}_log, FILENAME = N''D:\MSSQL16.DATA\MSSQL\DATA\{SERVERNAME}_log.ldf'' , SIZE = 73728KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )'

DECLARE @Create_Script varchar(MAX) = REPLACE(@Create_Template, '{SERVERNAME}', @server)

EXECUTE(@Create_Script)

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130')


IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
DECLARE @Action_Template varchar(MAX) = '[{SERVERNAME}].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = ''enable'''

DECLARE @Action_Script varchar(MAX) = REPLACE(@Action_Template, '{SERVERNAME}', @server)

EXECUTE(@Action_Script)
end

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET ANSI_NULLS OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET ANSI_PADDING OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET ARITHABORT OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET  DISABLE_BROKER')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET RECOVERY FULL')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET  MULTI_USER')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET DB_CHAINING OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF )')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET QUERY_STORE = OFF')

EXECUTE('ALTER DATABASE ' + @server + ' SET  READ_WRITE')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 0;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET MAXDOP = PRIMARY;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = OFF;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = PRIMARY;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = ON;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = PRIMARY;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = OFF;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = PRIMARY;')

/****** Create the user, then assign the user as DB_OWNER to the table ******/
EXECUTE('USE master; CREATE LOGIN ' + @user +' WITH PASSWORD=N'''+ @user +''', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;')

EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; CREATE USER ' + @user + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @user)
EXECUTE('USE '+ @server + '; ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER ' + @user)

GO

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(255);
    SET @msg = 'An error occurred: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR (50002, 10, 127);
END CATCH
```

Without the `TRY` and `CATCH` this script was working completely fine. It was run directly on the management Studio.

However how this script is now I get the following error message:

> Der Datenbankkontext wurde in "master" geändert.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server SQL, Line 131
>   Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von ")".

It suddenly has an error on line 131 which would be the line at the end with `CREATE LOGIN` after the comment.

Could you please tell me why there is suddenly a problem with this line and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move that last `GO` out of the `TRY` block, to after the `END CATCH`.  The batch terminator, `GO`, is allowed between transactions, but the `TRY - CATCH` needs to be in the same batch.